# Is SHCreateDirectoryEx available in Windows Vista/7?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I've seen in the docs for SHCreateDirectoryEx that it might be unavailable in Windows versions after Windows XP SP2 or 2003. Specifically, it says:

> This function is available through Windows XP Service Pack 2 (SP2) and
>   Windows Server 2003. It might be altered or unavailable in subsequent
>   versions of Windows

But what is its status right now? Is it available in Vista/7? Is is safe to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be available unless explicitly stated, but you can always use `GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(_T("Shell32.dll"),_T("SHCreateDirectoryEx"))` to check (or use dumpbin).

According to dumpbin, its available in windows server 2008 R2 SP1, which uses a similar kernel to windows 7, so I'd say its available, but might be removed in future versions (aka MS wants you to avoid using it if possible).

Comment: So I'd be better off not using it because future versions/service packs might break any code that uses it, right?

Comment: @MikMik: yes, your program will only be compatible from XP to win7, but might break on future OSes, requiring updates, so rather just save yourself the hassle now :)